# Android XML elements position changed after fomatting

Tags: android, android-layout

I updated my AS to 3.5 yesterday. I usually format code with `CTRL + ALT + L`. Today I am facing a weired issue. My included toolbar is getting last position of `LinearLayout` automatically after formatting code. Any suggestions please to remove this bug? I am facing this issue after updating AS.